# Hover style isn't applied to copied HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a node,I success,but i don't copy the hover function of the node to my application.The hover has nothing to do.and i want to run with ie8.
this is my html:

```html
<div id="appendCell" style="color:green; color:red">
    <button>clickMe</button>

</div>

<div id="addedCell" class="btnStyle" style="display:none">
        clickBtn
</div>
```

this is my css:

```css
.btnStyle{
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    background: orange;

}

.btnStyle:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

this is my jQuery code:

```js
$("#appendCell").find("button").click(function () { //当点击后触发
  $(this).before($("#addedCell").html());
});
```

Comment: Can't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I add the #addedCell node success.but the hover function of .btnStyle class don't run.I want to the hover run.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're copying only the *contents* of `#addedCell`, not its classes, etc. - so your copied content has no `.btnStyle` class. Consider cloning the whole div, and then un-hiding it:

```
$("#appendCell").find("button").click(function () {
  $(this).before(
    $("#addedCell").clone().removeAttr('id').show()
  );
});
```

Note that we're also removing the `id` of the cloned element, since IDs must be unique in the document.

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/uCnvD

Comment: Thanks everybody. According Paul provided the answer.I success.

Comment: And i think of another path to get the hover run.I want to use 'delegate' function or 'on' function to delegate the btn processing the hover function.                                                       for example:                                                          $
$("#table").append("<div class='btnStyle' style='display:block'>clickBtn</div>");
$("#appendCell").find("button").live("hover", function(){
 $(this).css("cursor","pointer");